# Multiline string in Azure Pipelines

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines

Can I use a [multiline YAML string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3790497/185123) in Azure Pipelines?

Using the ASP.NET Core (.NET Framework) template I tried multilining the `msbuildArgs` but that didn't work.

```yaml
- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: >
       '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package'
       '/p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true'
       '/p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\WebApp.zip"'
       '/p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

> MSBUILD : error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified.
>   Switch: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true

---

Reviewing the [string reference documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#string) I don't see any about this topic.

Comment: How are things going? Could you get useful information from my updated answer?

Comment: Hi @LeoLiu-MSFT - GTG, both answers worked, thanks for following up!

Comment: [update documentation request](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/6412)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I always use the [YAML block chomping operator](https://yaml-multiline.info/) like this

```
msbuildArgs: >-
  /p:DeployOnBuild=true
  /p:WebPublishMethod=Package
  /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true
  /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true
  /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\WebApp.zip"
  /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"
```

Works well and makes things crystal clear and neat

Comment: Well for my AzureCLI task in YAML, it required arguments like this [arguments: '-param XYZ' ] and so when I broke it up it was similar to yours except that I did not put minus sign after greater than sign and remove the single quotes as well. Note that square brackets are just for clarity here.

Answer (score 5):

You can just put `'` in the start and the end of the `msbuildArgs`:

```yaml
- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build solution **\*.sln'
  inputs:
    vsVersion: latest
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package 
    /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true'
```

Answer (score 5):

> Multiline string in Azure Pipelines

Shayki Abramczyk pointed out the key to the this error.

> Just put **one** `'` in the start and the end of the msbuildArgs
>   without having to configure for each MSBuild argument

As test, following YAML work for me:

```yaml
- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build solution YourSolution'
  inputs:
    solution: $(solution)
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

Note: The variable `$(solution)` should point to a specific solution `.sln` or project `.csproj` file instead of `**\*.sln`. If you have one more solution in your repo, you may get the error `Only one project can be specified`.

**Update:**

> but I don’t want super long run-on line as in your answer provided. I
>   want to split across multiple lines!

If you do not want to super long run-on line as in MSBuild arguments, you could split them directly, but pay attention to **indentation**, like:

```yaml
- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build solution YourSolution'
  inputs:
    solution: $(solution)
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true
                  /p:WebPublishMethod=Package 
                  /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true 
                  /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true 
                  /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\WebApp.zip" 
                  /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

As test, it works fine.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Leo Liu - appreciate the answer but I don’t want super long run-on line as in your answer provided.  I want to split across multiple lines! 

Comment: @spottedmahn, Got you! Let me check if it can be divided into multiple lines, will let you know when I have the result.

Comment: @spottedmahn, You can split them directly, but pay attention to indentation. Check my updated answer for some more details.